# juniper vpn network connect osx 10.6.8

Tags: macos, vpn, juniper

Juniper **Network Connect.app** stopped working for me out of the blue, i made no upgrades recently. i see the following log, what else can i investigate?

```
Process:         ncproxyd [5322]
Path:            /usr/local/juniper/nc/7.1.0/ncproxyd
Identifier:      ncproxyd
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  Network Connect [5319]

Date/Time:       2012-11-20 10:00:28.254 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000000000038a
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x1106e8aa 0x11000000 + 452778
1   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x11019eff DSRouteUtils::RouteTableIterator::next() + 19
2   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x1104df7a RouteMonitor::get_curr_routes() + 304
3   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x1104ee11 RouteMonitor::takeSysRoutesSnapshot() + 39
4   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x1104effe RouteMonitor::init(unsigned int) + 18
5   ncproxyd                        0x00005ab4 start + 12248
6   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x11018de6 DSIPC::call_function(void (*)(...), char const*, int*, int) + 100
7   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x11019b10 DSIPC::handle_message(DSIPCMessage*) + 672
8   net.juniper.DSCoreServices      0x11019d82 DSIPC::receive_message(unsigned char*, int) + 596
9   ncproxyd                        0x0000553a start + 10846
10  ncproxyd                        0x00002bea start + 270
11  ncproxyd                        0x00002b05 start + 41

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fd382 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fda9c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fcf59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fccfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fc781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fc5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fc412 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fc9a8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x937fc5c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00214f60  ebx: 0x1106e815  ecx: 0x00000380  edx: 0x000003dc
  edi: 0x00000380  esi: 0x00214f80  ebp: 0xbfffecc8  esp: 0xbfffec30
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x1106e8aa   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x0000038a

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x8ffd +ncproxyd ??? (???) /usr/local/juniper/nc/7.1.0/ncproxyd
   0x2a000 -    0x50fff  libssl.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7) <9203FADE-F4F2-2245-A32E-BD88819D314D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
   0x5f000 -   0x114fe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7) <AACC86C0-86B4-B1A7-003F-2A0AF68973A2> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
0x11000000 - 0x11078fdb +net.juniper.DSCoreServices 2.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) /Library/Frameworks/net.juniper.DSCoreServices.framework/Versions/7.1.0/net.juniper.DSCoreServices
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4163b  dyld 132.1 (???) <4CDE4F04-0DD6-224E-ACE5-3C06E169A801> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x90017fe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <B328FA0A-899C-4FC4-F2AC-2FDC08819CD2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x90a69000 - 0x90a75ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x90a76000 - 0x90a83ff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <DDC9C397-C35F-8D7A-BB24-3D1B42FA5FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x91166000 - 0x91169fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x9152f000 - 0x91573fe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <74F05E64-2A68-BA10-CCD4-128D164E5A0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x9168a000 - 0x91755fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <7C16D9C8-6F41-5754-17F7-2659D9DD9579> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x91756000 - 0x91758fe7  com.apple.ExceptionHandling 1.5 (10) <03218275-EBEC-39AA-895A-BA72A5FDBB7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExceptionHandling.framework/Versions/A/ExceptionHandling
0x91b6f000 - 0x91c6ffe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <BE7FCD73-03B5-25A4-FCA4-D4980F1488D6> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x92460000 - 0x9250dfe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x9349d000 - 0x934bffef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.15) <F38894EA-2C13-7FC5-C084-94DA0B5B6B68> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x935ee000 - 0x9362bff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <50E4D49B-4F61-446F-1C21-1B2BA814713D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x937d6000 - 0x9397dff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x93e46000 - 0x93fc1fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x94cd1000 - 0x94d7dfe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <DEDCD006-389F-967F-3405-EDF541F406D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x94d8c000 - 0x94db2ffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x94e58000 - 0x950beff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <3FA54D69-5476-78DD-0AFC-D6697263890E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x950cb000 - 0x9514bfeb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <7AE32A31-2B8E-E271-C03A-7A0F7BAFC85C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x95800000 - 0x9580efe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x9580f000 - 0x95855ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x9594a000 - 0x95953ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <6AA6DDF6-AFC3-BBDB-751A-64AE3580A49E> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x9652a000 - 0x96552ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E761F29A-328B-29D9-3DF0-023F2C21E500> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x96553000 - 0x965f0fe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <15B47388-16C8-97DA-EEBB-1709E136169E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x968be000 - 0x96bdeff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <5C59805C-AF39-9010-B8B5-D673C9C38538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x98921000 - 0x98954ff7  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <BF9673D5-2419-7120-26A3-83D264C75222> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x98977000 - 0x98af9fe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <50A70082-F800-93D8-1A7C-C95AAB1F352C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x98e20000 - 0x98e7dff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x99706000 - 0x997bffe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <52438E77-55D1-C231-1936-76F1369518E4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x99f33000 - 0x99f9dfe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x9a96f000 - 0x9abe0fef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <69B3441C-B196-F2AD-07F8-D8DD24E4CD8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x9abf4000 - 0x9abf4ff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```